# Is there a way to transform the rectagle drawn by glDrawTex?

Tags: opengl-es

As the OpenGL spec states all transformations are ignored by design, but is there an easy way to draw a texture as glDrawTex does, but transforming the pixels with a matrix before?

Comment: There is no `glDrawTex` function. Perhaps you're thinking about something else. What function are you referring to?

Comment: @NicolBolas: most likely author is talking about OES_draw_extension for OpenGL ES which provides glDrawTexOES function.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cann't you simply modify x/y/z arguments for glDrawTex function to transform your texture in position you want?
But if you want to rotate texture, then simply draw textured quad using two triangles. It's very simple. Assuming you have OpenGL ES version 1.1:

```
const float v[] = {
    0,   0,    0, 0,
    0, 128,    0, 1,
  128,   0,    1, 0,
  128, 128,    1, 1,
};

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 4*4, &v[2]);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 4*4, &v[0]);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

(I'm assuming you are drawing using orthographic projection, and 128 is size of texture)

This way texture position can be modified using modelview matrix. Also texure matrix can be used to modify how texture is applied to triangles.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am aware that I could quite easily draw a Quad myself, but I just wondered if there was an alternative that didn't need me to allocate yet another float array and sending data over the bus.But since it's just a few lines of code, I will mark it as answered.